# Questions about VideoPlayer

Tags: unity-game-engine

Why does video player's frame count change at the end of playback? How can I determine the end of playback? Can only be implemented in the following way?

```css
if ((ulong)GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().frame >= GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().frameCount-1)
{
   Debug.Log("VideoPlayer play完毕");
}
```

When it starts playing
Warning message:
First video frame not zero: 2 (0.066667s). Result may be out of sync. Please make sure tracks all start at 0 in D:/xxx.mp4

Comment: Please Don't post the image or screenshot instead copy and paste the entire code and provide the [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This looks like C++, not C. Please ensure you use the correct language tags when asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can reliably check if videoplayer is playing by querying its .isPlaying property

```
IEnumerator VideoPlayerCheck()
{
  var vp=GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
  vp.Play();
  while (!vp.isPlaying) 
  {
    Debug.Log("Playback not started");
    yield return null;
  }
  while (vp.isPlaying) 
  {
    Debug.Log("Playing");
    yield return null;
  }
  Debug.Log("Playback stopped");
}
```